# Trouble forcing text to wrap

Tags: html, css, layout, word-wrap

I am attempting to put several messages in a thread-like layout. To see the result of what I have, go here: http://jsfiddle.net/sunjay03/Aykqc/embedded/result/

If you adjust the width of the screen, you will see that the text in the lower message does not layout properly. As well as that, I can't seem to get the date to always go to the very right of the screen.

Here is the link to the full jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sunjay03/Aykqc/

Here are some images of what I'd like to happen:
[image: preview with large width]
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled around with your fiddle and made this of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/S7drj/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="messages">
    <div class="message">
        <div class="message-image">
            <img src="http://www.sunjay.ca/images/logo_notext.gif" alt="profile_image">
        </div>
        <div class="message-body">
            <div class="message-name">
                <span class="message-date">Nov. 15, 2010</span>
                <h3>John Smith</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="message-text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="message-image">
            <img src="http://www.sunjay.ca/images/logo_notext.gif" alt="profile_image">
        </div>
        <div class="message-body">
            <div class="message-name">
                <span class="message-date">Nov. 15, 2010</span>
                <h3>Joe Smith</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="message-text">
                <p>Aliquam commodo dui at mauris tempus eu commodo nunc commodo. Quisque accumsan semper sapien, quis tristique odio egestas ac.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    margin: 20px;
}

.message
{
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
}

.message .message-image
{
    padding: 5px;
    float:left;
}

.message .message-body
{
}

.message .message-body .message-name
{
}

.message .message-body .message-name h3
{
}

.message .message-body .message-text
{
}

.message .message-body .message-date
{
    float: right;
}
```

Is that how you want it?

Answer (score 1):

How's this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGdBG/)**?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="name">John Smith</div>
    <div class="date">Nov. 15, 2010</div>
    <div class="content">Aliquam commodo dui at mauris tempus eu commodo nunc commodo. Quisque accumsan semper sapien, quis tristique odio egestas ac.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="name">John Smith</div>
    <div class="date">Nov. 15, 2010</div>
    <div class="content">Aliquam commodo dui at mauris tempus eu commodo nunc commodo. Quisque accumsan semper sapien, quis tristique odio egestas ac.</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="name">John Smith</div>
    <div class="date">Nov. 15, 2010</div>
    <div class="content">Aliquam commodo dui at mauris tempus eu commodo nunc commodo. Quisque accumsan semper sapien, quis tristique odio egestas ac.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.name {
    float:left;
}
.date {
    float:right;
}
.content {
    clear:both;
}
.container {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-left:115px;
    background: url(http://www.sunjay.ca/images/logo_notext.gif) no-repeat;
    min-height: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think using background images is really an option.

Comment: Supposing this threads are like in any other forums images will change with each post. Therefore it is necessary to use an image tag.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but amosrivera is correct. I need to be able to use several different images. The images were the same in the jsfiddle just as an example. Thanks for your help though!